# migrate old azure function API's to new azure function without changing url

Tags: azure, api, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

earlier we were using azure function app (lets name it func-dev-01 ) for making http function with HTTP trigger which create url as
**https://{function_name_dev}.azurewebsites.net/api/{name}?code=12345678910 ,
**
but for some reason now we are migrating to new azure function app (lets name it fun-prod-01) which create url
** https://{function_name_prod}.azurewebsites.net/api/{name}?code=11121314151617
**
Note: name of both azure function and code are different which is making 2 url's different

How to get same url as old azure function using new azure function ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The DNS is provided / handled by AZURE. For such reasons, you should use custom domain and map the way you want:

e.g.
https://mycustomdomain.com (prod)

https://dev.mycustomdomain.com (dev)